# Python character math using stack

Tags: python, stack

I received an interesting challenge in an algorithm Meetup. Given an input string, return a string in which all substrings within brackets have been replicated n times, where n is the integer outside the brackets. Characters outside brackets should simply be concatenated to the substring inside. For example:

- **2[ab]** should return **abab**
- **a[3[bc]]** should return **abcbcbc**
- **2[ab[cd]]** should return **abcdabcd**

I've started implementing the solution using a stack, but I've got the feeling that my approach of checking each de-stacked character for a bracket is off, anyone have any suggestions? Code is below

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def length(self):
        return len(self.items)

def is_number(s):
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def character_math(charstr):
    final_output = ""
    substring = ""
    for i in charstr:
        myStack.push(i)

    for m in range(myStack.length() - 2):
        destacked = myStack.pop()
        # We want to go to the inner-most right bracket
        if destacked != "]":
            substring += destacked
        if destacked == "[":
            possible_multiplier = myStack.pop()
            if is_number(possible_multiplier):
                final_output += int(possible_multiplier) * substring
            else:
                final_output += possible_multiplier[::-1]
                break
        final_output += substring[::-1]
    return "Final output is ", final_output

myStack = Stack()
# 3[ab[cd]] should return 'abcdabcd'
sample_str = '2[ab[cd]]'
print(character_math(sample_str))
```

Comment: That's true, and maybe I could have been a little more specific. I'm struggling with identifying the right pattern for evaluating a series of characters as they come off a stack as my current approach is too cumbersome to handle different input strings. Thanks to Mathieu for doing that by pointing to recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do that is to use a recursive algorithm. The idea is to repeat a function until a condition is match. Here is the code I used, it works on your examples, and I don't think I forgot one of the possibilities.

```
# -*-coding:Utf-8 -*

Input = "2[ab[cd]]"

def Treatment(STR):

    # Exit the treatment. That's the end condition.
    if "[" not in STR:
        return STR

    # Find the inner [], in this case, the "cd" part
    Bound1_ID = len(STR) - STR[::-1].index("[") - 1
    Bound2_ID = STR.index("]")

    # Separate STR into : First_part + middle between [] + Last_part
    Last_part = STR[Bound2_ID + 1:]

    # First_part depends if there is a number or not
    try:
        Multiplier = int(STR[Bound1_ID - 1])
        First_part = STR[:Bound1_ID - 1] 
    except:
        Multiplier = 1
        First_part = STR[:Bound1_ID]

    Middle_part = STR[Bound1_ID + 1: Bound2_ID] * Multiplier

    # Assemble the new STR :
    New_STR = First_part + Middle_part + Last_part

    # Recursive command, repeat the function on the new STR
    return Treatment(New_STR)

print (Treatment(Input))
```

EDIT : That's what it does :

- First iteration : "2[ab[cd]]"
- Second iteration : "2[abcd]"
- Third iteration : abcdabcd => No more "[" so stop here.